# What does "not to look over the best scenes" mean in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrasal-verbs

> ... a detailed analysis will help them to notice the most important film elements and not to look over the best scenes.

I think that means that a good review of a movie (the full text is about that) should help you to don't watch the important scenes without paying attention.

Comment: More context is needed.  It could be that they meant “overlook” but “look over” could also work but the sentence would would have a completely different meaning.

Comment: The text is about "how to write reviews" and the complete paragraph is: Sometimes, an inexperienced audience needs some instructions for the right way of watching a certain movie. A detailed analysis will help them to notice the most important film elements and not to look over the best scenes. Moreover, particular movies have a confusing plot with unexpected twists that need additional explanations.

Comment: In that case I think they meant ***overlook*** not *look over*.